# QField Sync used in different Laptop/Machine

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qfield, qfieldsync

I configured a QField Package project using my machine/laptop. It worked great and was packaged successfully. Then, after I collected data from the field, I synchronized it using the QField Sync Plugin in QGIS, everything worked well and the collected data in QField was synchronized completely.

However, one of my colleagues tried to sync the data from QField into his machine, but unfortunately, he encountered an error.

> QFieldSync : The data has been synchronized successfully but the
> original project (//original project location) could not be opened.

Is there a way I can fix this so that he can also synchronize the data collected from QField to his machine?

We are currently testing the end-to-end process since we are also going to deploy this workflow in one of our field offices.

Answer (score 1):

Configure export/import path in QGIS , after you install your plugins go to preference, and set the same path where the files from QFIELD are